# Android Studio: Open app from a service intent and get data from the same app

Tags: android, service

I need to open my app from a serviceintent, but this one need to get data from the same app, and I have no idea how to make this.
Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: What kind of data?

Comment: need to receive an int number to know when to start the activity.

Comment: what code do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you mean, but my guess is that you want to send an extra.

Use this when creating the intent in your service:

```
intent.putExtra("KEY",intValue);
```

When starting the activity, in the `onCreate`

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("KEY",defaultValue);
```